# exposing a RIA Service (Domain Service) as a SOAP web service

Tags: c#, web-services, ria

I am trying to expose a RIA domain service as a SOAP web service for backward compatibility with a legacy application.

I've read around that I need to add:

```
<domainServices>
  <endpoints>
    <add name="OData"
         type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ODataEndpointFactory, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </endpoints>
</domainServices>
```

to the existing , but it seems that "domainServices" is not a valid node.

Why is this happening? Am I missing some step?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid. it's just the schema for web.config is old and hence the warning. It should work fine though!
There's a [post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/205849/484343.aspx) where they talk about the schema in detail if you are interested.

Comment: Hey shadowfoxmi, thank you for your answer. I've actually tried to expose the RIA Service with both Odata and Soap, and it works great.